# How can I calculate interrupt latency in macOS?

Tags: macos, terminal, interrupt

When I was studying about I/O in my OS Class, I came to a following screenshot from an macOS looking terminal which is showing the total number of interrupts generated in 10 seconds-[Image Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYDiu.jpg)

can anyone please suggest from which command could I get this output, specially Macs with new ARM chips?

Answer (score 2):

On intel macs, the command you want is called `latency`. See `man latency`. You can run it like so:

```
sudo latency -n /System/Library/Kernels/kernel
```

I'm not sure if this command is available for ARM based macs or not.